# Authorization Header is ignored in PHP Backend from Angular 2 http get request

Tags: php, angular, ionic2

I am trying to send an authorization header from my ionic 2 app with following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MembersService {

    private baseUrl = 'http://xxx';
    constructor(private http: Http) { 

    }

    getMemberlist() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`, this.jwt())
                .map(res => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => resolve(res.v_members));
        });
    }

    private jwt() {
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token });
            console.log(headers);

            return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        }
    }
}
```

On PHP Backend I look into the headers with:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
file_put_contents("headers.txt", print_r($headers, true));
```

and get follwing output:

```
Array
(
    [Host] => xxx
    [Connection] => close
    [Access-Control-Request-Method] => GET
    [Origin] => http://localhost:8100
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko$
    [Access-Control-Request-Headers] => authorization
    [Accept] => */*
    [Referer] => http://localhost:8100/
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch
    [Accept-Language] => de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
)
```

I have already added following to .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1,PT]
```

When I connect to the API with postman the Authorization Header is present:

```
Array
(
    [Authorization] => Bearer test_token
    [Host] => xxx
    [Connection] => close
    [Cache-Control] => no-cache
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.$
    [Postman-Token] => 9b51b6fe-2c24-564c-9998-1acb5b02136e
    [Accept] => */*
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch
    [Accept-Language] => de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
    [Cookie] => PHPSESSID=uiboq2m0isfgb16kfrr9dtbji1
)
```

What am I missing here?

edit:

code setting the localstorage:

there is no problem in the response from the login. the user and token is set in localstorage

```
   login(username, password) {
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
            .map((response: Response) => {
                let user = response.json();
                if (user && user.token) {
                    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: How did you set the token in the `localstorage`? Could you post your code related to that?

Comment: I have no access to my code atm. But if you want to know, if the if-condition is met, I can confirm this, as the output of console.log(headers); shows me the correct header.

Comment: I have added the code where the localstorage is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
The problem was, that I misunderstood the error response. The HTTP-Request from angular is sending a preflight that got rejected with a the 401 response from my backend. The actual request was never send. The header I posted above is the header of the preflight, therefore without any authorization stuff. After I changed my backend to properly respond to the preflight, the request is sent including the authorization-header.